# Fetching from CoreData with RKObjectManager in RestKit

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, nsmanagedobject, restkit-0.20

I am trying to understand how RestKit's fetching of objects works. As far as I understand it, when I call,

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/mypath/objects" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        // Use objects that are returned.
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Handle error
    }];
```

Restkit will attempt to load the objects at the specified path from the web-service and call the success block once the objects have been retrieved. It will also update the core data object graph with the mapping I provide before it calls the success block. What if I only want to the objects that are in core data? How do I access those objects? Should I use the sharedManager's managedObjectStore's mainQueueManagedObjectContext to perform NSFetchRequests directly on it and only call `getObjectsAtPath:parameters:success:failure:` if I want the Core Data persistent store to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand it

Yes, basically. RestKit will go and get the data from the server at the specified path, deserialise it and map it into objects based on the mappings and response code / descriptor. If you have specified to use Core Data then it will save the results before calling the success block.

> What if I only want to the objects that are in core data

Then you don't use RestKit, you just access the `mainQueueManagedObjectContext`, often with an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Boom, exactly what I was looking for. That confirms my suspicions. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: One question @Wain, if we do that, I guess we will block the main thread (ie user interface) for a while, isn't it? Apart from that, what about if we access the data using that and at the same time there is a request ongoing? Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo RestKit will create background threads for you to run network requests and mapping operations